# UIImagePickerController button

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a problem with my `PickerController`.

I have a `launcherView` with 4 buttons. Each button opens another `View`.

When I open my `PickerController`, all works fine but when I return to my `LauncherView` and open my `PickerController`, the "Cancel" and "Take picture" buttons are not clickable.

If I click the "Change camera" button (with my iPod new generation 2 camera), buttons are clickable.

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Did you reference the class correctly? This is a sample to see if fixes your issue, make sure the delegate is there and allows Image Editing = YES:

```
    self.imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
self.imagePickerController.allowsImageEditing = YES;
self.imagePickerController.delegate = self;
self.imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
```

Comment: I  don't want to image was editable!
And my source is type camera.
Delegate and alloc init are ok